# Why Can't we use a instead of &a to store value of variable a in C programming lang?

Tags: c, user-input

```
void main()
{
int a;

printf("Enter a value to store :");

scanf("%d",&a) ;  // Why Can't we use a instead of &a to store value of variable a ???

printf("value of a is %d", a) ;
printf("\naddress of a is %d", &a) ;
getch() ;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Learn about functions and the reason for passing by pointer. Then it will become apparent.

Comment: As for your "question" (which you really should write separately and clearly outside code snippets), C only have *pass by value* when passing arguments to functions. That means values are copied, and arguments inside a function are then totally unrelated to the original expression used when calling the function. What `scanf` is doing is ***emulating** pass by reference*.

Comment: `int a[1]; scanf("%d", a); printf("you entered %d.\n", *a);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in C parameters in function calls are passed by value. If you just give it `a`, then there's no way to actually store a value. Sure, it can change that `a` in the funtion, but then it only changed its copy of the value, not the original value. It doesn't even want that value, it wasnts to write a value. Therefore, what it needs is the *address* of a value, so it can use that address to write the new value there.

> Why Can't we use a instead of &a to store value of variable a

Good question! What you have in mind is a concept called "Pass by reference", and some programming languages actually do this. There, the `a` you pass would be the same `a`, not just a copy of it, so if it is written to, the original is changed, too. For instance, in C++:

```
int a = 1;
void increase(int& myInt) {
    myInt++;
}

int main() {
    increase(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `2` is printed, because the original `a` was increased. Without the ampersand in the function signature, `1` would be printed because only the copy is modified.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The parameters in function calls. Sorry for being unclear, I added it to the answer. As I had some doubts, I wanted to double check it and it seems that the University of Utah is struggling with this... https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/c_functions.html

Comment: Can you please explain then why we do not use & [pass by value] for printf().   Please & Thank You!

Comment: `printf` doesn't modify the variables you give it, so it is perfectly fine with a copy and doesn't need a pointer or reference to the original. The exception is when you want to print strings, then it expects a pointer to the first character in the string. So for instance if `char buf[32]` is my string, I could do `printf("string: %s", &buf[0])`. Or just `printf("string: %s", buf)`.